# About gif animation

Tags: animation, base64, gif

When posting a gif animation base64-encoded using shareAsync () of FBInstantGameAPI v6.2, when posting from a PC browser, the gif animation is played and when posting from the facebook app, the gif animation is not played.

There is no difference in implementation between pc and smartphone.

Please let me know if someone know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Would you mind to provide more information about the problem? Post your code, etc.